# No indicator for search with no results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, android-app

There's just whitespace at the bottom. There's no way to know if there's no result or if the search is still ongoing.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot make me feel weird with all that white space

Comment: @Marc-Andre maybe it's a program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After version v0.1.6 we will show a message when the list of results is empty.